# How to escape my variable to run my regular expression against?

Tags: c#, regex, escaping

My string contains what could be perceived as regex.

```
var x = "a&\b";
```

I am trying to replace out any non-numeric or alphabetical character.

```
var z = Regex.Replace(x, "[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Expected result: `ab`
Actual result: `a`

I understand that `\b` is a regular expression word.

***I also understand I can `var x = @"a&\b";`, however, I wish to escape the variable, not the assignment.***

how can I escape my variable`x`?

I have tried `Regex.Escape()`

Comment: `\b` is ASCII [backspace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backspace_character) (0x08) character, not a [regular expression for word boundary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#atomic_zerowidth_assertions). It is not clear what is your exact goal... Maybe `"a&\b".Replace("\b", "\\b")`?

Comment: The string x can contain any value. Is that a safe enough escape? Do I just perform that replace and also use Regex.Escape()?

Comment: Can you please edit your question to match accepted answer? Your "expected `ab`" is very confusing...

Comment: My apologies. After using Dereks solution, I thought i saw `ab`. I have unticked as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial regular expression *would* work - *if* the String contained what was expected.

This is because `\` in a [String Literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228362.aspx) (except for a [Verbatim String Literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14583874/verbatim-string-literals-v-escape-sequences)) is the escape character. While this is mentioned in the question, the *fundamental premise in the question is wrong* and it has *nothing* to do with "\b is a regular expression word" because the string in question is *not* used as the [regular expression pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
Literal  ->  actual String data
"a&\b"       {'a', '&', BELL}
"a&\\b"      {'a', '&', '\', 'b'}
@"a&\b"      {'a', '&', '\', 'b'}
```

As such, it is the original string which *does not* contain a 'b' - but rather the [BELL character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character) - which is removed due to *not being accepted* by the original regular expression replacement. BELL is, after all, not an alphanumeric character. Even if it wasn't removed, it would not display as a 'b' character .. because it's BELL.

While there is *no* generalized way in the .NET standard library<sup>1</sup> to reverse-escape from `"\b"` to `"\\b"`/`@"\b"`, you may find [this transformation function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23072711/how-to-convert-a-two-character-string-n-into-actual-char-n/23072946#23072946) useful - then you could go `x = EscapeLikeALiteral("a&\b")`, after which `x == "a&\\b"`, and obtain the desired "ab" result, even with the original regular expression<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> The `Regex.Escape`/`Regex.Unescape` methods are *only* suitable for use with regular expression *patterns* and not this generalized task of "reverse escaping strings to literals".

<sup>2</sup> Strictly speaking, the original regular expression is *not* an alphanumeric filter as it also allows spaces and dashes.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your code how about using \W?

\w Matches any word character [a-zA-Z_0-9]

\W Matches any non-word character [^a-zA-Z_0-9]

So I am suggesting you use:

```
var z = Regex.Replace(x, "\W", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

You might be able to use:

```
var z = Regex.Replace(x, "[^a-zA-Z_0-9]", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

But I think the first one is nicer.

Comment: How does this reproduce "ab" ?

Comment: The original regular expression would work just as well in this case - it also has a slightly difference meaning of "alphanumeric". While these are approximate alternatives, neither answers the question or address the fundamental issue.